# show loading icon until the page is load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to show a loading icon to users until the page elements are fully loaded. How can I do that with javascript and I want to do it with javascript, not jquery?

[Here](https://www.googlesciencefair.com/en/) is a link how google does it
How can I do this?
triggering some function on onload event or something like this .. I know it will be done somewhat like this or any other ways to do it?
Or there is some event for it?

**UPDATE**
I did something using display property I hide the body element but and onload of body tag I change its property but where to put the loading icon and add more interactivity.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="load"></div>
    <div id="contents">
          jlkjjlkjlkjlkjlklk
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'interactive') {
       document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility="hidden";
  } else if (state == 'complete') {
      setTimeout(function(){
         document.getElementById('interactive');
         document.getElementById('load').style.visibility="hidden";
         document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility="visible";
      },1000);
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
#load{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    background:url("/loading.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}
```

**Note:** 
*you wont see any loading gif if your page is loaded fast, so use this code on a page with high loading time, and i also recommend to put your **js** on the bottom of the page.*

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/6AcAr/ - with timeout(only for demo)
http://jsfiddle.net/47PkH/ - no timeout(use this for actual page)

**update**

http://jsfiddle.net/d9ngT/

Comment: it is showing content and loading icon at same time i want the content to be hidden until the whole page loads... in the mean time the loading icon appears and when the page is loaded i want loading icon to go away and the content to appear.

Comment: thnx buddy now can you tell me how YouTube disables the loading icon from title bar and shows a red bar on top top which fills from left to right.

Comment: @Sky loading icon from the title bar? you already have the loading icon when your page loads why do you need the loading bar like youtube?

Comment: Why do you have document.getElementById('interactive'); ?

Comment: Im populating some dropdowns with XMLHTTP, while this is loading I would like show the load screen. Any ideas ?

Also what about initial page loading depending on speed of internet connection. So, bring up the load screen while page is loading, and hide when page is fully loaded.

Comment: @Viscocent your personal website's URL is broken. any way we can connect?

Comment: @Viscocent, your code is working fine on my website but when page is loading then all content is greyed out like it should except header which is made of Bootstrap `nav`. Please let me know what change I should make to greyed out header part too like all other content.

Comment: @Sky Youtube uses ajax requests to fetch data without reloading the page. While the data is being fetched the site does its loading animation, which I think is a % of how much has been loaded = the length of the red bar.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to put the loader in the website.

HTML:

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#loading {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background: #fff url('images/loader.gif') no-repeat center center;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#loading').fadeOut(3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: OP specifically said, "no jQuery"

Answer (score 2):

add  class="loading" in the body tag then use below script with follwing css code

```
body {
            -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
            transition: background-color 1s;
        }
        html, body { min-height: 100%; }
        body.loading {
            background: #333 url('http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
            -webkit-transition: background-color 0;
            transition: background-color 0;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0;
            transition: opacity 0;
        }
```

Use this code

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var removeLoading = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        body.className = body.className.replace(/loading/, '');
    }, 3000);
};
removeLoading();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0qpuaeph/

Answer (score 2):

HTML, CSS, JS are all good as given in above answers. However they won't stop user from clicking the loader and visiting page. And if page time is large, it looks broken and defeats the purpose.

So in CSS consider adding

```
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
```

Also, instead of using gif files, if you are using fontawesome which everybody uses now a days, consider using in your html

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin">
```

Answer (score 1):

Element making ajax call can call loading(targetElementId) method as below to put loading/icon in target div and it'll get over written by ajax results when ready. This works great for me.

```
<div style='display:none;'><div id="loading" class="divLoading"><p>Loading... <img src="loading_image.gif" /></p></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loading(id) {
    jQuery("#" + id).html(jQuery("#loading").html());
    jQuery("#" + id).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML page

```
<div id="overlay">
<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assest/website/images/loading1.gif" alt="Loading" />
 Loading...
</div>
```

Script

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
 //PAGE IS FULLY LOADED 
 //FADE OUT YOUR OVERLAYING DIV
 $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score -6):

firstly, in your main page use a loading icon

then, delete your `</body>` and  `</HTML>` from your main page and replace it by

```
<?php include('footer.php');?>
```

in the footer.php file type :

```
<?php
    $iconPath="myIcon.ico" // myIcon is the final icon
    echo '<script>changeIcon($iconPath)</script>'; // where changeIcon is a javascript function whiwh change your icon.
    echo '</body>';
    echo '</HTML>';
?>
```

Comment: op asked for js solution

Comment: I want to show a loading(preloader) icon until my page loads. When the page full loads then i want to replace the loading icon with the html elements(contents of page).

Comment: it's the js function which will change the icon !!
i just show how to call the function to do what he want

Comment: @angel this was tagged `javascript` `html` and `css`, this post has no `php` tag.