# Pop up on browser loads

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have done one sample project, In that i'm getting records from database and i'm showing it in browser in table form.While getting records from database browser loading 1 min (Approx).I want to show a popup that should appear on browser up to the time browser loads.I have tried with some javascript code but it loads upto some given time like 5 seconds or 10 seconds.

Can any one please guide me!

Comment: check this link you can get it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906956/show-loading-icon-until-the-page-is-load

Comment: check this link, put popup instead of gif image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906956/show-loading-icon-until-the-page-is-load

Answer (score 0):

```js
function yourFunction(){
$("#loading").show();

//do something 

//For example I am just delaying 5 second to hidde loading 
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   $("#loading").hide(); //after 5 seconds it will hide, you can use this at the end of your all operations
  }, 5000);


}

yourFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/12755/screenshots/1037374/hex-loader2.gif" id="loading" style="fixed"/>
```

Instead of popup use any loading gif image.

```
<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" style="position:fixed;"/>
```

In your js, when you start inserting operation write this code

```
$("#loading").show();
```

At end of your function write this

```
$("#loading").hide();
```

Comment: should i use any js library for this

Comment: I dont have much idea on jquery and javascript

Comment: Ya you need jquery library, just add this scrrpt into your code <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i tried but im not getting Can you give me a sample code how to use the code that you suggested.