# Loading Skeleton Effect as a Background color for Image

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a set of `images` in my page, I set `background-color` to that image, so when page loads until the image loads it shows the `background-color`.

I want to show skeleton loader like effect as a background for the image with keyframes or anything related like that.

Is it possible using purely CSS? Or tell me any alternate solutions.

Comment: no it is not possible with pure css , you have to use javascript setTimeout function for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show loading icon until the page is load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906956/show-loading-icon-until-the-page-is-load)

Comment: Check this snippet: https://codepen.io/gabrieltomescu/pen/BWwrYY

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
background: black;
}
.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}
@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-ring">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This spinner is not dynamic it will be on page forever , even is all images are loaded

Comment: He can copy that spinner and put it on an absolutely positioned image with z-index:1, yes the spinner will still running but it will be covered by the image when it's lodaed